# manual cell shifting in a tikz-cd diagram

Tags: positioning, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams, cell

Is there a way to shift single cells in a tikz-cd diagram?
My approach so far was to put the contents of the cells inside a node, so that i can shift this node with the usual tikz options

```
xshift, yshift
```

The problem with this solution is, that this shifts also the rest of the diagram, which is "in the way" of the shift operation.
Here is a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\node (1-1) {a}; & \node (1-2) {b}; \\
\node (2-1) {c}; & \node (2-2) [yshift=1cm] {d}; \\
\ar[from=1-1, to=1-2]
\ar[from=1-1, to=2-1]
\ar[from=1-2, to=2-2]
\ar[from=2-1, to=2-2]
\end{tikzcd}
```

This code does move "d" 1cm upwards as expected, but it does also move the first row of the diagram 1 cm upwards, an effect I want to avoid.

By the way, the way I added the arrows to the diagram seems to be the only possibility to do so, when using nodes inside tikz-cd cells.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One centimeter is quite big. What's the effect you'd like to achieve?

Comment: I need to draw some big diagrams which require some finetuning. An example would be the diagram on page 31 (resp. page 39 in the pdf) of this paper: http://gauss.math.yale.edu/~mg622/tricats.pdf

Comment: I would prefer a solution with tikz-cd, since this would guarantee a uniform appearance of all the diagrams in my thesis. And therefore my idea was to jam the diagram in a tikz-cd matrix of some reasonable size and then to shift the nodes in some appropriate way.

Comment: If just a couple are not on a grid, you might try `\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\tikzcd@savedpaths{shifted node}` but you'll have to do absolute positioning for the node. If it isn't gridlike at all, see http://mirrors.sorengard.com/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf#subsection.3.3

Comment: Thank you Hood Chatham, I will try your second suggestion this evening. I don't quite understand your first suggestion yet, probably because I have no clue about pgf (just used the front ends tikz and tikz-cd so far). Anyways, probably I will have to shift quite a few nodes per diagram, so the second approach might be preferable anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tikz-cd` allows you to modify the distance of a single row putting `[<your_width>]` after `\\` and of a single column putting it `&` in the first row of the diagram.

Taking advantage of that, you could create a row/column that contains the node(s) you would like to positioning a little bit above/below or left/right and, playing with the row/column distance, you can get what you want.

See the nodes `eeee` and `ffff` in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a41empaperpt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    aaaa&[-10pt] &&[-14pt] bbbb\\
    &eeee\ar[urr]&&\\[-16pt]
    &&ffff\ar[ul]&\\[-16pt]
    cccc\ar[uuu]\ar[uur]&&&dddd\ar[ul]\\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I like this solution a lot. In comparison to my approach it has the additional advantage, that there is no need to use a node in every cell of the tikz-cd diagram.