# Manually placing cells in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have been trying to make [manual cell shifting in a tikz-cd diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410377/manual-cell-shifting-in-a-tikz-cd-diagram) work in my case, but I am running into some issues when my diagram gets too big.

My desired diagram is something like

```
\documentclass[a41empaperpt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    & S(F) \arrow[ddddl, "\operatorname{id}"']\arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"] \arrow{rr} & &  F \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"]\rar{R} & Z(F) \arrow[ddddddl, bend left = 75, dotted, "\beta"]\arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"] \\
    & & \circled{2} & & \\
    & IS(F) \arrow[ddl, "\partial_0^*", "\simeq"' ] \arrow[dddd, bend left = 90, "0", "\circled{3}"'] \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{id}"]\arrow[rr] & & I(F) \arrow[dddd, bend left = 30, "\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*"] \rar{R} & IZ(F) \arrow[ddddl, bend left = 45, dotted, "\alpha"]\\
    \\
    S(F) \arrow[ddr,  "0"']\arrow[r, "\operatorname{pr}^*", "\simeq"'] &[-10pt] IS(F) \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*}"] &  & \circled{1} \\
    \\
    & S(F)\arrow[rr]  & & F
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But the bendy arrow goes through `\circled{3}`, which I would like to manually move it to the left to avoid collision with the arrow.
EDIT: Now the bendy arrow does not collide, but the `\circled{3}` is smaller than the other ones.

Using the linked question, I can do something like

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & IS(F) \arrow[rrr] \arrow[d, "\operatorname{id}"]\arrow[dd, bend left = 75, "0"]&[-30pt] & & I(F)\\
    S(F) & IS(F) \arrow[d, "\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*"]&\circled{3}& \circled{1}& \\
    & S(F) &&& F \\
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{equtation}
```

Which seems to work, except when I add a top row it breaks:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & S(F) & F \\
    & IS(F) \arrow[rrr] \arrow[d, "\operatorname{id}"]\arrow[dd, bend left = 75, "0"]&[-30pt] & & I(F)\\
    S(F) & IS(F) \arrow[d, "\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*"]&\circled{3}& \circled{1}& \\
    & S(F) &&& F \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC Sorry, what part doesn't work?

Comment: `\circled` is not defined and the class of the document is missing.

Comment: @AndréC Right, thanks. Hopefully fixed now!

Comment: I got these error `! Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: `tikzcd` is not ended correctly. Please always make sure that yuour example actually compiles.

Comment: @daleif Yes, apologies! Now it compiles on my end atleast

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What's the MWE? What's wrong with it? What do you want to get?

Comment: @AndréC If you look at the code for the first diagram, the bendy arrow goes through `\circled{3}`. I want to avoid this by manually moving the node to the left so that the bendy arrow goes around it, rather than through it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Roughly, do you want to move the arrow to the **left** or the `\circled{3}` to the **right**?

Comment: @AndréC Ideally the `\circled{3}`, as even if I make `bend left` large, it doesn't go all the way around.

Comment: Everything is doable. If I understood correctly, the `\circled{3}` must be to the **right** of the arrow. The arrow stays where it is now, but we move the `\circle{3}`, to the **right**, right?

Comment: @AndréC Depends on the perspective I suppose :) Looking at the diagram, I want to move `\circled{3}` to the _left_ in the diagram. From the perspective of the arrow (it is going down) I suppose it is to the the right. I want it to look like the big diagram from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3188.pdf) page 11.

Comment: And the `0` label next to the `\circled{3}`, what do we do with it? I speak of left and right in an absolute way, that is to say as TikZ does, *left* is the **left side** of sheet a4, *right*, the **right side**.

Comment: @AndréC The ` 0 ` label is on the arrow, and it should be on the right (in the absolute way).

Comment: From what I understand, the `3` is absolutely placed by you. Why don't you make it a second arrow label?

Comment: @AndréC That's quite clever and is certianly a good solution. Now it is just a little small compared to the others, but I suppose I can live with that.

Comment: Post your new MWE, we'll make it better.

Comment: @AndréC Done, let me know if it doesn't compile on your end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

As explained in the comments, the problem is that `\circled{3}` is placed in a cell and therefore cannot be moved. Just place a second node at the arrow to place this `3` at the desired location. To do this a style `circled 2` is created.

I colored in blue so that you can see the changes. I created a style called `circled 2`. The code is commented with `%<--`

```
\documentclass[a41empaperpt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\tikzset{circled 2/.style={draw,circle,font=\normalsize,inner sep=2pt}}     %<-- new style circled 2
            
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    & S(F) \arrow[ddddl, "\operatorname{id}"']\arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"] \arrow{rr} & &  F \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"]\rar{R} & Z(F) \arrow[ddddddl, bend left = 75, dotted, "\beta"]\arrow[dd, "\operatorname{pr}^*"] \\
    & & \circled{2} & & \\
    & IS(F) \arrow[ddl, "\partial_0^*", "\simeq"' ] \arrow[dddd,blue, bend left = 90, "0", "3"{circled 2,swap,xshift=-2pt}] \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{id}"]\arrow[rr] & & I(F) \arrow[dddd, bend left = 30, "\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*"] \rar{R} & IZ(F) \arrow[ddddl, bend left = 45, dotted, "\alpha"]\\
    \\
    S(F) \arrow[ddr,  "0"']\arrow[r, "\operatorname{pr}^*", "\simeq"'] &[-10pt] IS(F) \arrow[dd, "\operatorname{\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*}"] &  & \circled{1} \\
    \\
    & S(F)\arrow[rr]  & & F
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much for your help! If you don't mind, can you explain how the ` &[-10pt] ` works, I couldn't get it to bend to my will :). I also need similar things for other diagrams, can I ping you if I run into trouble there (though it should be easier than this one).

Comment: @ThePuix The `&[-10pt]` reduces the column sep (created by this `&`) by `10pt`. Its documentation can be seen from [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 20.3.2 _Setting and Adjusting Column and Row Spacing_, option `row sep`.

Comment: @ThePuix Yes, you can send me a message whenever you want. As for the rest, muzimuzhiZ has answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the errors come from some extra `'`. I deleted them and made a little changes in your code, you can easily find the changes: some `{name=...}`, an `|[alias=is]|`. I placed the circled numbers using the key `phantom`, you can see its use with the new arrow from `S(F)` to `I(F)` and the two arrows at the end.

```
\documentclass[a41empaperpt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
            
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=5em]
  & S(F)\arrow[rr] \arrow[d,"\operatorname{pr}^*"]
             \arrow[ddl,"\operatorname{id}"swap]
             \arrow[rrd,phantom,"\circled{2}"]
  && F\arrow[r,"R"]\arrow[d,"\operatorname{pr}^*"] 
  & Z(F)\arrow[d,"\operatorname{pr}^*"]
            \arrow[dddl, bend left = 75, dotted, "\beta"] \\ 
  &IS(F)\arrow[rr] \arrow[d,"\operatorname{id}"] 
             \arrow[dl,"\partial_0^*", "\simeq"swap]
             \arrow[dd,bend left = 90, "0"{name=0},""{name=o,left}]
  && I(F)\arrow[r,"R"]
       \arrow[dd,bend left = 30, "\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*",""{name=p,left}]
  & IZ(F)\arrow[ddl, bend left = 45, dotted, "\alpha"]\\
  S(F)\arrow[r,"\operatorname{pr}^*", "\simeq"swap] \arrow[dr,"0"swap]
  & |[alias=is]| IS(F)\arrow[d,"\operatorname{\partial_1^*-\partial_0^*}"]\\
  & S(F)\arrow[rr]
  && F
  \arrow[Rightarrow,from=0,to=p,phantom,"\circled{1}"]
  \arrow[Rightarrow,from=is,to=o,phantom,"\circled{3}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The circled numbers appear always centered between the corresponding labels. Note that you don't need the extra rows to place them. I also added `swap` to the leftmost arrows, I believe it looks better if the `id` and `0` arrows are placed outside the triangles.
[image]

Comment: This is a very nice solution as well, thank you so much!

Comment: I’m glad that you can use it :)